# running awk command in perl script

Tags: perl

Want to run the awk command inside backtik operator in perl.  It's giving me a error. I tried escaping the quotes , pipe but nothing seems to work.

```
my @fieldCnt=`head -1 $inputFileDir/$cmdParams{mas}|awk -F, \'print NF\'`;
```

Comment: Why are you running awk inside perl?

Comment: where are the flower braces(`{}`) in your awk command?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Missing braces was the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just do it within the perl script rather then using awk.  If I understand what you are trying to achieve, you are looking for the number of items in the line separated by a comma, then

```
 # Open the file for reading
 open my $fh,"$cmdParams{mas}" or die "Unable to open: $cmdParams{mas}";
 my $firstLine = <$fh>;  # Get the first line
 close($fh);  # close the file
 my @items = split(',',$firstLine);  # Get the items separated by comma's
 $numberOfFields = scalar(@items);   # Get the count of the number of items
```

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dont want to open the files. I want to try a one line code using awk. AWK braces was missing that was the right answer